# Find the non zero values and frequency of those values in R

Tags: r

I have a data which has two parameters, they are data/time and flow. The flow data is intermittent flow. Lets say at times there is zero flow and suddenly the flow starts and there will be non-zero values for sometime and then the flow will be zero again. I want to understand when the non-zero values occur and how long does each non-zero flow last. I have attached the sample dataset at this location https://www.dropbox.com/s/ef1411dq4gyg0cm/sampledataflow.csv

The data is 1 minute data.

I was able to import the data into R as follows:

```
   flow <- read.csv("sampledataflow.csv")
summary(flow)
names(flow) <- c("Date","discharge")
flow$Date <- strptime(flow$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
sapply(flow,class)
plot(flow$Date, flow$discharge,type="l")
```

I made plot to see the distribution but couldn't get a clue where to start to get the frequency of each non zero values. I would like to see a output table as follows:

```
Date    Duration in Minutes
```

Please let me know if I am not clear here. Thanks.

**Additional Info:**

I think we need to check the non-zero value first and then find how many non zero values are there continuously before it reaches zero value again. What I want to understand is the flow release durations. For eg. in one day there might be multiple releases and I want to note at what time did the release start and how long did it continue before coming to value zero. I hope this explain the problem little better.

Comment: Run length encoding using `rle`? eg `rle(flow$discharge)`?

Comment: your data consists of only 33k odd values. Rest have `Timestamp=""` and `flow = NA`

Comment: Arun, this is just a sample, I haven't uploaded all the data. Actually, I have around 230k data. I have added additional info on my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first point is that you have too many `NA` in your data. In case you want to look into it. 
If I understand correctly, you require the count of continuous 0's followed by continuous non-zeros, zeros, non-zeros etc.. for each date.

This can be achieved with `rle` of course, as also mentioned by @mnel under comments. But there are quite a few catches.

First, I'll set up the data with non-NA entries:

```
flow <- read.csv("~/Downloads/sampledataflow.csv")
names(flow) <- c("Date","discharge")
flow <- flow[1:33119, ] # remove NA entries

# format Date to POSIXct to play nice with data.table
flow$Date <- as.POSIXct(flow$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Next, I'll create a `Date` column:

```
flow$g1 <- as.Date(flow$Date)
```

Finally, I prefer using `data.table`. So here's a solution using it.

```
# load package, get data as data.table and set key
require(data.table)
flow.dt <- data.table(flow)
# set key to both "Date" and "g1" (even though, just we'll use just g1)
# to make sure that the order of rows are not changed (during sort)
setkey(flow.dt, "Date", "g1") 
# group by g1 and set data to TRUE/FALSE by equating to 0 and get rle lengths
out <- flow.dt[, list(duration = rle(discharge == 0)$lengths, 
        val = rle(discharge == 0)$values + 1), by=g1][val == 2, val := 0]

> out # just to show a few first and last entries

#              g1 duration val
#   1: 2010-05-31      120   0
#   2: 2010-06-01      722   0
#   3: 2010-06-01      138   1
#   4: 2010-06-01       32   0
#   5: 2010-06-01       79   1
#  ---                        
#  98: 2010-06-22      291   1
#  99: 2010-06-22      423   0
# 100: 2010-06-23      664   0
# 101: 2010-06-23      278   1
# 102: 2010-06-23      379   0
```

So, for example, for `2010-06-01`, there are 722 `0's` followed by 138 `non-zeros`, followed by 32 `0's` followed by 79 `non-zeros` and so on...

Comment: @ Arun : Thank you so much for this answer. Yes, it does definitely solve my problem to find the duration of each zeros and non-zeros. Another nice addition would be the average values of zeros & non-zeros at those duration if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I think this answers your question. Obtaining an average is straightforward and I'll leave it to you.

Answer (score 2):

I looked a a small sample of the first two days

```
> do.call( cbind,  tapply(flow$discharge, as.Date(flow$Date), function(x) table(x > 0) ) )
      2010-06-01 2010-06-02
FALSE       1223        911
TRUE         217        529    # these are the cumulative daily durations of positive flow.
```

You may want this transposed in which case the t() function should succeed. Or you could use rbind.

If you jsut wante the number of flow-postive minutes, this would also work:

```
 tapply(flow$discharge, as.Date(flow$Date), function(x) sum(x > 0, na.rm=TRUE)  ) 
#--------
2010-06-01 2010-06-02 2010-06-03 2010-06-04 2010-06-05 2010-06-06 2010-06-07 2010-06-08 
       217        529        417        463          0          0        263        220 
2010-06-09 2010-06-10 2010-06-11 2010-06-12 2010-06-13 2010-06-14 2010-06-15 2010-06-16 
       244        219        287        234         31        245        311        324 
2010-06-17 2010-06-18 2010-06-19 2010-06-20 2010-06-21 2010-06-22 2010-06-23 2010-06-24 
       299        305        124        129        295        296        278          0
```

To get the lengths of intervals with discharge values greater than zero:

```
tapply(flow$discharge, as.Date(flow$Date), function(x) rle(x>0)$lengths[rle(x>0)$values]  )
#--------
$`2010-06-01`
[1] 138  79

$`2010-06-02`
[1]  95 195 239

$`2010-06-03`
[1]  57 360

$`2010-06-04`
[1]   6 457

$`2010-06-05`
integer(0)

$`2010-06-06`
integer(0)

... Snipped output
```

If you want to look at the distribution of these durations you will need to unlist that result. (And remember that the durations which were split at midnight may have influenced the counts and durations.) If you just wanted durations without dates, then use this:

```
flowrle <- rle(flow$discharge>0)
flowrle$lengths[!is.na(flowrle$values) & flowrle$values]
#----------
 [1] 138  79  95 195 296 360   6 457 263  17 203  79  80  85  30 189  17 270 127 107  31   1
[23]   2   1 241 311 229  13  82 299 305   3 121 129 295   3   2 291 278
```

Comment: Hi Dwin, thank you for your answer. But it seems I didn't explain my problem clearly. One needs to check the non-zero value first and then find how many non zero values are there continuously before it reaches zero value again. The result you showed has the daily non-zero minutes I think. What I want to understand is the flow release durations. For eg. in one day there might be multiple releases and I want to note at what time did the release start and how long did it continue before coming to value zero. I hope this explain the problem little better.

Comment: That's easy enough to provide. You just need to be prepared to deal with irregular numbers per day.

Comment: DWin, thank you so much for your updated answer. I was wondering if it is possible to output average nonzero discharge values for the length of interval you calculated ?

Comment: The function to do that is `mean` and given the numbers of NAs, you would be wise to use the `na.rm=TRUE` option. (AND please construct a smaller dataset next time.)